# User: x is not authorized to perform: (sts:DecodeAuthorizationMessage)`

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am facing an issue while trying to provision my EC2 instance through Terraform. However, to debug that issue I am trying to decode the encoded authorization failure message.

But when trying to call that sts decode API I am getting:

> Error: A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the DecodeAuthorizationMessage operation: User: xxx is not authorized to perform: (sts:DecodeAuthorizationMessage)

Now I don't know which specific permission should I give to my IAM user to be able to decode this message?

Updates:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Based on the error message quotued, it seems that [sts:DecodeAuthorizationMessage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_DecodeAuthorizationMessage.html) permissions are required:

> **Decodes additional information** about the authorization status of a request from an encoded message returned in response to an AWS request.

Subsequently you could add the following policy as an [inline policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html#inline-policies), for example, into your IAM user or its group:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowStsDecode",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:DecodeAuthorizationMessage",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The same could be added through [Customer Managed Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html#customer-managed-policies) if inline policies are not desired.

Comment: Thankyou for comment. However, i am unable to find any policy by name while trying to attach them to the group. Please check the screenshot in my original question.

Comment: @Maven You have to create such managed policy with that permission yourself, or add the permission as an inline policy directly to the group.

Comment: I'm having this issue with a role that has admin access to everything . . .

Comment: @BenG You should make new question dedicated to your issue.