# How can I apply my local cli after changed IAM on AWS management console

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, aws-cli, eventual-consistency

- Prerequisite

  - I usually use [aws-mfa](https://github.com/broamski/aws-mfa)
  - I tried to `terraform apply`
  - I got a problem of insufficient IAM. But it might be resolved by: [User: x is not authorized to perform: (sts:DecodeAuthorizationMessage)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63065797/user-x-is-not-authorized-to-perform-stsdecodeauthorizationmessage)

    - The answer makes sense.
- What I did

  - Added the IAM Permission to my policy(this attached to my group)
  - Checked sts get-caller-identity on my local as my IAM User.
  - IAM Policy Simulator told me that the IAM Group includes my IAM User is permitted to perform sts: DecodeAuthorizationMessage...
- Problem

  - The IAM I added seems to be not applied on my local.

    - it still shows `<my IAM USER> is not authorized to perform: sts:DecodeAuthorizationMessage with an explicit deny in an identity-based policy`
- Ask

  - Anyone can resolve the problem?
  - And, please let me know that the timing gap of between aws cli and aws management console. How much does it takes?
  - Moreover, how can I immediately apply to aws cli after IAM changed on aws management console?

Comment: If there's an [explicit deny](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html#AccessPolicyLanguage_Interplay) in some IAM policy associated with this IAM user then you'll need to identify where that deny statement is and understand why it's there before you can understand whether or not it's reasonable to remove it. You won't be able to bypass this restriction with that deny statement in place.

Comment: @jarmod Thank you so much for your immediate reply.
I checked all associated policy attached to my IAM User. And I found some IAM policy based on other IAM groups I belong. But it just denied MFA-device-things permissions. (Our team makes the members disabled to use AWS unless enable MFA-login)

Comment: I used IAM Policy Simulator and found the denies.. So I would like to check the root of the denies.

Comment: There's a page that helps with [Troubleshooting access denied error messages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/troubleshoot_access-denied.html). Is it possible that this action was explicitly denied simply because you didn't supply an MFA token?

Answer (score 0):

Add this as an inline policy to your IAM user,

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowStsDecode",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "sts:DecodeAuthorizationMessage",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```